# Numpy Array python dimension uniform

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn

I have 2 dimensional array with 15 elements in one dimension and variable length in second dimension

for example

```
>>print abc.size()
15
>>print abc[0].size()
5873
>>print abc[1].size()
9825
```

How can i make array dimensions uniform either using numpy or skikit sparse array. the data is hog features of an image.

Comment: What is `abc`?  A `numpy` array does not have a `size` method.  It has a `size` attribute.  But if it is an array, you should give us the `shape` and `dtype`, not the `size`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to align all the arrays to the left, and pad to the right with zeros, then you could first find the maximum length with

```
max_len = max([abc[i].size() for for i in range(abc.size())])
```

and then pad using [`zeros`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html):

```
import numpy as np

for i in range(abc.size()):
    abc[i] = np.append(abc[i], np.zeros(max_len - abc[i].size())
```

Answer (score 1):

We have here two possible cases:

1. `abc` is *a list* of images, and for each image `abc[i]` is the set of hog features of the image `i`.
2. `abc` is *one* image and each `abc[i]` is the *i*-th hog feature of the image

For the first case, the image sizes or the hog parameters (size for the neighbour) differ from one image to another, so you need to adjust the parameters in order to calculate the hog features properly for all the images (if you want fixed sized descriptors).

For the second case, your hog computation is not correct (it shouldn't happen that the sizes of the hog descriptors are different for the same image).

So, in any of the cases, there is no way of `resizing` your arrays. You need to fix your hog computations.

---

Edit: related to your problem, you have a dataset of different size images. The are two possible *common* approaches for image classification with hog descriptors. But first, a quick summary of HOG:

- HOG splits the image in `M x N` windows of size `m x n` each and calculates a histogram oriented gradients with fixed `W` number of bins (number of orientations) in that window. Hence, you will end up with `M x N x W` features. Features are usually flattened in a 2D vector of size `K x W` with `K = M x N`.

Now, for classification there are 2 common approaches:

1. Combine all the features of an image in one, this is, perform an average (or weighted average or norm) over the `K` features to end up with a vector of size `W` for each image (the number of orientations).
2. To preserve (more or less) the spatial relationship of the features, another more common approach is to concatenate all the features in order to end up with a flattened 1D vector of size `Z`, with `Z = K x W`/

From your data, I think you are trying to perform the 2nd step. The problem you are facing is that the images have different size, and therefore, for a fixed window size `m x n` the number of features differ from one image to another.

The way you could fix that, is by fixing the number of features `M x N` you want, and for a given image, calculate `m = height / M` and `n = width / N` and calculate the HOG descriptors with that custom `m x n` window size (which is different for every image). This way, you will end up with an `K = M x N` vector with the same `K` (but different window size) for every image.

With a fixed `K` and therefore fixed `Z` you would be able to perform classification.

I don't know which library are you using for computing the HOG, but `m x n` window size parameter should be easy to manually set up for every image.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Tell me more about the first case, how can can make same number of hog features for all images or any other image feature which results in same number. What do you suggest for image classificaton>

Comment: @Aunn Raza what kind of classification are you looking for? Assigning a class to an image (this image is sea, or sky or natural image or synthetic image or wathever..) or assigning a class to every pixel/area/superpixel of an image as in (this area of the image is grass, this area is brick...)

Comment: first one, actually object recognition on caltech101 dataset.

Comment: Thanks man! helped a lot and i am using scikit's skimage and sklearn for feature extraction and classification respectively

Comment: @Aunn Raza glad it helped :D with *pixels per cell* and *cells per block* parameters of scikit's hog you can *easily* setup same `M x N` for every image.